# I want to display dynamic marker on google map using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

```
var locations = '<?php print_r(json_encode($locations)) ?>'
console.log(locations); 
var mymap = new GMaps({ 
el: '#mymap', 
lat: 31.5204, 
lng: 74.3587, 
zoom:6 }); 



mymap.addMarker({ 
lat: 31.5204, 
lng: 74.3587, 
click: function(e) { alert('This Is Lahore, Pakistan.'); } });
```

this is response

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":2,"latitude":"37.33068424","longitude":"37.33063124","attacked_by":"1","created_at":"2020-02-09 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-02-16 00:00:00"}]
```

how can i add multiple pointers using this response lang lat?

Comment: look at the api [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers)

Comment: and its  new google.maps.Marker({position,icon,map}), you have to give position as {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044} not separate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have multiple lan,lat coordinates to add multiple markers like given below.

```
[
   {"id":1,"user_id":2,"latitude":"37.33068424","longitude":"37.33063124","attacked_by":"1","created_at":"2020-02-09 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-02-16 00:00:00"},
   {"id":1,"user_id":2,"latitude":"38.33068424","longitude":"38.33063124","attacked_by":"1","created_at":"2020-02-09 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-02-16 00:00:00"},
   {"id":1,"user_id":2,"latitude":"39.33068424","longitude":"39.33063124","attacked_by":"1","created_at":"2020-02-09 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-02-16 00:00:00"}
]
```